# Realmのデータを失わずにカラムを追加してマイグレーションする方法

Tags: swift, ios, realm

```
class UserClass: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var user: String = ""
    let colorData = List<Color>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "user"
    }
}

class VariousColor: Object {
    dynamic var colorData = NSData()
    let chidLink = LinkingObjects(fromType: UserClass.self, property: "data")
}
```

を

```
class UserClass: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var user: String = ""
    dynamic var kisetsu: String = ""
    let colorData = List<Color>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "user"
    }
}

class VariousColor: Object {
    dynamic var colorData = NSData()
    let chidLink = LinkingObjects(fromType: UserClass.self, property: "data")
}
```

といった感じにカラムを追加したいのですが、App store上のアプリで使用してるデータを移行する方法がわかりません。（そもそもあるのでしょうか）

Answer (score 0):

リリース後にモデルのデータ構造を変更した場合には、マイグレーションを行う必要があります。

Realmにおけるマイグレーションとは、モデルのデータ構造に変更があったをRealmに伝えることと、古いデータ構造から新しいデータ構造に実際のデータを移行することです。

まず、１つ目について、データ構造の変更が意図的であることをスキーマバージョンを変えることでRealmに教えます。そうでないと、Realmはデータ構造が既存のファイルと一致しないことが意図的なのか、間違ったファイルを開いたのか区別できないからです。

スキーマバージョンは`Realm.Configuration`オブジェクトを使って指定します。

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

上記のように`schemaVersion`を指定して`Realm.Configuration`オブジェクトを作り、Realmをインスタンス化する際のパラメータとして渡します。

このとき、古いデータ構造から新しいデータ構造にデータの移行がない場合はこれだけでOKです。既存のファイルのデータ構造を変換し、新しいデータ構造のファイルにデータをコピーするところまで自動的にRealmがやってくれます。
ここでいう「データの移行」とはデータの変換を伴うかどうかです。
例えば、[ドキュメント](https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/#section-40)にあるような

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

`firstName`プロパティと`lastName`プロパティを一つの`fullName`プロパティに変換するような場合です。

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var fullName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

このような場合は、さらに`migrationBlock`引数を使って、データの変換処理を書きます。

今回の場合、新しく`kisetsu`というプロパティを追加しただけなので、そのプロパティに対して古いデータから何かを設定することはないと思いますので、`migrationBlock`を書く必要はありません。

スキーマバージョンを上げてRealmを開くだけで、自動的に新しい`kisetsu`プロパティが追加され、それ以外のデータはそのままコピーされます。

より詳しくはドキュメントをご覧ください。
https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/#section-40

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。プライマリキーの変更に際しても特にmigrationブロックに書く必要はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、説明を誤解しておりました。すなわち、デバッグ時にマイグレーションは行われず、アプリがApp storeでリリース、インストールされた時に行われるということでしょうか？よってApple storeの場合申請する時にスキーマバージョンを上げて申請するという解釈で問題ありませんでしょうか。

Comment: それで合ってますが、そういう疑問があるということは、ユーザーのデバイスにファイルが作られるということがイマイチ分かっていらっしゃらないのだと思います。Realmでマイグレーションが必要なのは、既存のファイルを開こうとしたときに、データ構造が異なっている場合です。それは通常なら既存のアプリをアップデートしたときに起こります。リリースしていないアプリを自分の手元でいくら変更してもユーザーのデータには当然影響はありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。理解しました。最後に2点だけ確認させていただきたいのですが　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・スキーマバージョンを調べる方法はありますでしょうか
・マイグレーションの際にApp delegateに書いたconfigはDBスキーマ変更後書いたままである必要がありますでしょうか。

以上大変申し訳ないのですがですがご教授いただければ幸いでございます。

Comment: `schemaVersionAtURL(fileURL:)`メソッドで引数で指定したファイルのスキーマ‌​バージョンを調べることができます。ですが、普通はこのメソッドを使うことはありません。スキーマバージョンは自分で指定するものなので（何も指定しなければ最初は0）、スキーマ‌​バージョンがいくつかは普通は自明なので。基本的に、スキーマバージョンは下げることはできませんし、マイグレーションの処理もそのままにしておく必要があります。例えば、アプリを３回リリースし、３回ともスキーマの変更を伴うとします。このとき、ユーザーはアプリを毎回アップデートしてくれるとは限らないので、あるユーザーはバージョン１から３という風に２を飛ばしてアップデートするかもしれません。そのような場合でもすべての変更が順番に適用されるように古いマイグレーションもそのまま残しておきます（まずドキュメントをご覧ください。そのような場合の説明が詳しく書いてあります。）。データの変換を伴わない場合などは、スキーマバージョンをただ上げていくだけですので、もっと簡単になります。Realmに限らずDBのマイグレーションは簡単ではないので、手元でいろいろ試してみることをお勧めします。